# Why mongoose.connect() works just fine when is not present as a method on the mongoose object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Given the following code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
console.log(mongoose);

mongoose.connect("my database url here")
```

How that everything works just fine - but the mongoose object does not have any connect() method attached to it? Here is the console.log print:

```
Mongoose {
      connections: 
       [ NativeConnection {
           base: [Circular],
           collections: {},
           models: {},
           config: [Object],
           replica: false,
           hosts: null,
           host: null,
           port: null,
           user: null,
           pass: null,
           name: null,
           options: null,
           otherDbs: [],
           _readyState: 0,
           _closeCalled: false,
           _hasOpened: false,
           _listening: false } ],
      plugins: [],
      models: {},
      modelSchemas: {},
      options: { pluralization: true } }
```

Don't get me wrong, I like magic stuff - but not not when i try to deeply understand how the entire mean stack fits together. The fact that I have no errors is not helping me this time.
All i know - it should be like this:

```
var myObj = {
    someMethodLikeConnect: function(nonBoringParameter){
      //and now this is a method.
    }
}
console.log(myObj); // it prints corectly
myObj.someMethodLikeConnect("foo"); // this works and it's expected.
myObj.connect("some URL"); // this gives: "myObj.connect is not a function" Error and it's also expected.
```

Is there anything like a prototypical inheritance going on? I mean this connect() method does not exist on the mongoose object but comes form another higher level thing (built by node context or smth- because some how node recognizes that we are working with "mongoose" module and not with "myObj"?)  -> and that is why it's not logged by my console?
Or am i missing something fundamentally about how JavaScript works?

This a nodejs app - i use Cloud9. I'm also new to programming. Tank you for taking the time to read this:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch here is correct, there is prototypal inheritance going on here.

Here is the code for the connect method:

```
Mongoose.prototype.connect = function() {
  var conn = this.connection;
  if (rgxReplSet.test(arguments[0]) || checkReplicaSetInUri(arguments[0])) {
    return new MongooseThenable(this, conn.openSet.apply(conn, arguments));
  }

  return new MongooseThenable(this, conn.open.apply(conn, arguments));
};
Mongoose.prototype.connect.$hasSideEffects = true;
```

When you log the Mongoose object alone, it will only have whats inside of that one object, not its prototype.

Now if you instantiate a new Mongoose object and log that? It will have the relevant functions.

Take a look at this quick JSBin I made to see exactly what I mean: [JSBIN LINK](https://jsbin.com/lizupu/edit?js,console)

Note the Mongoose docs here, click 'see code' at the bottom of the connect example:

[Relevant Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect)

Comment: Wow! I can't help myself but to say this: What a wonderful explanation!! Thank you so much:) I seen a lot of tutorials and i was thinking i got prototypal inheritance but until it stuck me in real life - the reality is - i never quite get it  - until now. There are a lot of nifty-grifty things that always slips tough my fingers.. Guys check out the [JSBIN LINK](https://jsbin.com/lizupu/edit?js,console) its totally on point.

Comment: Dude, thanks for the kind words! On that note, I wrote out a much longer version of a similar answer today, its gets into a lot more detail... 
At this point, I think it'll be a great read for you!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378373/javascript-constructor-is-not-executed/36378531#36378531