# JavaScript constructor is not executed?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

I'm attempting to implement an example I found on JavaScript inheritance, and the child object does not seem to be constructing as expected. In the example below, creating the jill instance does not return a Jill object and the methods from the child or parent cannot be called.

```
var Person = function() {
  this.name = "unnamed";
}
Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
  console.log("My name is " + this.name);
}
var Jill = function() {
  var jill = function() {
    Person.call(this);
    this.name = "Jill";
  };
  jill.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
  jill.prototype.constructor = jill;
  jill.prototype.expressJoy = function() {
    console.log("Huray!");
  };
  return jill;
}
var jill = new Jill();
console.log(jill instanceof Jill); // false
jill.expressJoy(); // error, is not a function
jill.sayName(); // error, seen if comment out previous line
```

Comment: `jill` is the actual constructor. No idea why you wrapped that in the `Jill` function. Was this supposed to be an IIFE, maybe?

Comment: Yep, @Bergi --looks like you had the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case `var Jill` acts like a regular function, not like constructor.
Change your code as shown below:

```
var Jill = (function () {
    function Jill() {
        Person.call(this);
        this.name = "Jill";
    };
    Jill.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
    Jill.prototype.constructor = Jill;
    Jill.prototype.expressJoy = function () {
        console.log("Huray!");
    };
    return Jill;
})();

var jill = new Jill();
console.log(jill);   // Jill {name: "Jill"}
console.log(jill instanceof Jill); // true
jill.expressJoy(); // Huray!
jill.sayName();    // My name is Jill
```

Now `Jill` is a "real" constructor that will generate objects as you expected. (BTW, A constructor name should start with an uppercase letter, according to good practice)

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally missed this part from the example.

Comment: @scader, so you know, with this method you would have to ensure that you always use `new` for each object creation. If you return `new jill()` to Jill (as in my example) you won't have to worry about missing `new` and the problems that can cause. _Every_ call to `Jill()` will return a new object.

Comment: @Andy, it sounds like : "Look at me, love me,  I'm better than he is ... ". Is this because you didn't get any upvote(or it's just the envy)?

Answer (score 1):

You are wrongly initiating the object,

```
var jill = Jill();
var obj = new jill();
```

The function `Jill` is returning a function `reference` not an `object`. And on top of that, returning function reference we have to create the `object` for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This is the corrected code, will edit with detailed explanation:

[JSBIN Example](https://jsbin.com/letabu/1/edit?js,console)

```
// This is your Person class, all "people" will inherit from this object

var Person = function() {
  this.name = "unnamed";
};
// add the sayName function to this prototype
Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
  console.log("My name is " + this.name);
};

// now we make a 'Jill' constructor;
var Jill = function() {
  Person.call(this); // bind this (Jill) to Person
  this.name = 'jill';
};

// create the correct prototype delegation here
Jill.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

// the above code, sets  Jill's constructor, to Person so we need to set 
// it back to Jill here:

Jill.prototype.constructor = Jill;

// add functions on Jill's prototype, these will only be on the Jill object not Person

Jill.prototype.expressJoy = function() {
    console.log("Huray!");
  };

// make a 'Jill'

var obj = new Jill();
console.log(obj instanceof Jill); // true
obj.expressJoy(); // "Huray!"
obj.sayName(); // "My name is jill"
```

Now more importantly you are mixing two types of instantiation patterns, prototypal and pseudoclassical, Person is the latter, while Jill is the former.

Take a look at this awesome picture from  the following blogpost by Ryan Atkinson:

[Blog Post](http://www.ryanatkinson.io/javascript-instantiation-patterns/)

[image: instantiation Patterns]

Comment: Those comments don't make much sense any more

Comment: Thanks for the awesome picture, @Omarjmh. Simplifying the object makes sense. It looks like the example i was using put it within the IIFE as they were working towards placing the code into a module loader.

Answer (score 0):

With your code you need to:

1) `return new jill();` in the inner function, and then

2) `var jill = Jill();` to call the function that creates the new instance.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/axpjwb1j/)

This is a less-complicated method.

```
function Person() {
  this.name = "unnamed";
}

Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
  console.log("My name is " + this.name);
}

function Jill() {
  Person.call(this);
  this.name = "Jill";
}
Jill.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Jill.prototype.constructor = Jill;
Jill.prototype.expressJoy = function() {
  console.log("Huray!");
};

var jill = new Jill();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n6jnmqgd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function Person() {
  this.name = "unnamed";
};
Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
  console.log("My name is " + this.name);
};

function Jill() {
    Jill.prototype.__proto__ = Person.prototype;

    this.name = "Jill";

    Jill.prototype.expressJoy = function() {
        console.log("Huray!");
    };

    return Jill;
};

var jill = new Jill();
console.log(jill instanceof Jill); // True
jill.expressJoy(); // Hurray !
jill.sayName(); // My name is Jill
```

Comment: `__proto__` is deprecated. Don't use it.